# How to run Asynchronous Logic Synchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, kafka-producer-api

I have the following method that uses Kafka to produce data into a topic:

```
public void Send(
    ProducerMessage<TKey, TValue> producerMessage, 
    string topic, 
    Action<McFlowProducerResult<TKey, TValue>> callback = default)
    {
       try
       {
        var kafkaProducerMessage = new Message<string, string>();
        
        // DeliveryHanlder logic is skipped?
        _producer.Produce(
            topic,
            kafkaProducerMessage,
            deliveryReport => DeliveryHandler(deliveryReport)); // TODO: How can I ensure the DeliveryHandler logic is executed without using async await Task?
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // Some exception logic
       }
}
```

The `DeliveryHandler` logic is as follows:

```
        // TODO: Execution never makes it into this function
        private async Task DeliveryHandler(DeliveryReport<string, string> deliveryReport)
        {
            var producerResult = new ProducerResult<string, string>(deliveryReport);
            
            if (!deliveryReport.Error.IsError)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Message Sent successfully to DLQ TOPIC");
                return;
            }

            _logger.LogError("Unable to send the message to DLQ TOPIC: {0}. Error Reason :{1}", 
                deliveryReport.Topic, deliveryReport.Error.Reason);
            
            if (deliveryReport.Error.Code == ErrorCode.NetworkException)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Sending message to DynamoDb");
                
                await _fatalErrorHandler.HandleError(producerResult);
            }
        }
```

And I have the following unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void ValidateDeliveryHandlerIsInvoked()
{
    var producerMessage = new ProducerMessage<string, string>(
        "aKey",
        "aValue",
        new Headers(),
        Timestamp.Default,
        0
    );
    
    ProducerResult<string, string> callbackResult = null;
    
    _mcFlowDlqProducer.Send(producerMessage, _topicName,
        (mcFlowProducerResult) =>
        {
            callbackResult = mcFlowProducerResult;
        });
    
    Assert.NotEmpty(callbackResult.Topic);
}
}
```

Kafka's `Send()` method receives 3 parameters: the `topic` to produce to, the `kafkaProducerMessage` which is the data to be sent, and an optional `Action<DeliveryReport<TKey, TValue>> deliveryHandler` which allows the user to retrieve the results of a produce operation.

My problem is with that 3rd parameter -- the DeliveryHandler (which is an async method).  When I run my above unit test, execution never makes it to the `DeliveryHandler` because the call is not awaited.

I cannot modify my `void Send(...)` method's signature because I need to have a Synchronous implementation of this method; so I cannot replace the `void` keyword with `async Task`.

How can I ensure that execution enters the `DeliveryHandler` method so that the `DeliveryHandler` logic gets executed without using `async Task`?

I've tried modifying the call to the DeliveryHandler to:

```
DeliveryHandler(deliveryReport).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

But my debugger tells me that execution still never enters the `DeliveryHandler` block.

Comment: `_mcFlowDlqProducer.Send(producerMessage, _topicName);` - where is `DeliveryHandler` here?

Comment: Use `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` to adapt callback-based asynchronous APIs to the `Task<TResult>` style. That said, while I'm unfamiliar with Kafka's C#/.NET library, I'd be very surprised if it didn't have built-in support for `Task<T>`-returning results which you can use in any `async` method...  and you should _not_ be invoking non-synchronous APIs from a synchronous context _unless_ you're absolutely certain of the conditions to avoid deadlocks (by preferring to use the thread-pool and synchronization primitives instead of calling `.GetResult()` willy-nilly).

Comment: _"I cannot modify my `void Send(...)` method's signature, so I cannot replace the void keyword with async Task."_ - **why** can't you modify it? How was/is this synchronous interface ever expected to work given it obviously crosses an IO boundary (which implies asynchronicity)?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy -- I've modified the test to include that logic.

Comment: **Your `DeliveryHandler` method won't compile**. You can't use the `await` operator in a method that lacks the `async` modifier (on the `await _fatalErrorHandler.HandleError(producerResult);` line) - and you must never use `async void` outside of WinForms or WPF.

Comment: @Dai -- I've updated the method signature to use `async Task`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to the end, as in:

```
_producer.Produce(
            topic,
            kafkaProducerMessage,
            deliveryReport => DeliveryHandler(deliveryReport).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution would be to create an overload for `Send`:

```
public Task SendAsync(
    ProducerMessage<TKey, TValue> producerMessage, 
    string topic, 
    Func<McFlowProducerResult<TKey, TValue>, Task> callback = default)
```

and then you can call `SendAsync` when you have an asynchronous callback.